# getting error for client = boto3.client('eventbridge')

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, boto3, aws-event-bridge

getting error for:

```
client = boto3.client('eventbridge')
```

```
botocore.exceptions.UnknownServiceError: Unknown service: 'eventbridge'. Valid services are xyz
```

I have upgraded my boto3 and botocore to the latest, but still this error didnt go away.
boto3 version -> Version: 1.26.29
and botocore version -> Version: 1.29.29

Comment: This error can be caused by a typo in the name of the service you are trying to use. Make sure you are using the correct name of the service and try again.

Comment: @ChaitanyaWaikar sorry that was a typo in the question statement, I edited the question. please look again.

Comment: import boto3  client = boto3.client('events') per documentation, https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/events.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```py
client = boto3.client('events')
```

The boto3 [EventBridge client](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/events.html)  is named `events`.

Pro Tip:  List the available service clients with `session.get_available_services()`

```py
session = boto3.Session(profile_name="my-profile", region_name="us-east-1")

services = [s for s in session.get_available_services() if s.startswith("event")]
print(services) # -> ['events']
```